# "no data" health status while deploying node app via beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I tried to deploy a simple node application ([code here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/samples/nodejs-v1.zip) via AWS Elastic BeanStalk by going with all default options except that I uploaded the sample application as default one didn't work.

In all my attempts, I eventually get "No data" error as health status. After 12-16 mins of wait, the last line in the logs say

```
Environment health has transitioned from Pending to No Data. Initialization in progress (running for 16 minutes). There are no instances.
```

Could someone please help me here?

Comment: did you figure this one out? I've been running for about 55 min now with the same message.

Comment: configuring a proper VPC helped. earlier the default instance wasn't part of any VPC so i chose custom config and added VPC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of others, I managed to resolve above issue by configuring VPC which wasn't configured by default.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the environment and the application. Then I went to the VPC console and deleted the default VPC. Then I created a new default VPC. In that VPC I had subnets as well.

Then I went back to Elastic Beanstalk and created a new application. I specifically chose Advanced Configuration. Under Network, I chose the new default VPC. Then configured one of the subnets to be public. For the RDS database, I chose both the subnets to be private. This configuration worked to get the sample app running.